# Force Sensitivity: How much potential in the Force can a human be born with naturally? (Legends or Canon Material)

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, the-force, biology, midichlorians

Ok so... I should probably break down what I mean - take Anakin Skywalker, has what is widely considered the greatest potential in the Force of all time, he was quite literally conceived by the Force itself in response to Plaeguis shenanigans, therefore he has high potential but how much force potential can someone be born with if they don't have force-sensitive parents or grandparents etcetera.

Example of my issues below.

Naga Sadow - Literally forced a Star to go supernova - Born to a species that is said to have a primal connection to the dark-side of the Force.

Marka Ragnos - Sith Pureblood same as above.

Arcan, Thexan, and Vaylin - Tenebrae and Senya Tirall's kids, both of whom were Force-Sensitive.

Galen Marek - Both his parents were Jedi.

Skywalker and Solo Family Lines - Anakin Skywalker is their frikkin Progenitor so yeah.

Darth Maul - Night Sister Clans are also force-sensitive species/most of the time.

So basically my question is, is it possible for a human with non-force sensitive origins to be born with potential on par with the likes of Vaylin, Vitiate, Marek, and Sadow?

Comment: The question in your title doesn't match the question in the body. You're asking multiple questions. You're asking for opinions... I recommend that you read the [tour] because I had to decide which reason out of several to flag your question for closing. :) I think you have an interesting start to a question, but as it stands, it's not good for the site.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Corrected to just the question in the title. Is that better?

Comment: I've clarified the title and removed the request for opinions (since we really want an answer based on facts) and I'm good.

Comment: Don't forget Yoda species, himself, Yaddle and the Kid from the Mandalorian.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Thanks, this is my first question ever so I really appreciate what you did to make sure it stayed open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Force is meant to be "democratical", is not a matter of birthright.

We have indeed examples of "nobody" who became extremely powerful in the Force, even if their family have little to spare with the Force. I'll take two big examples, one for canon and one for legend.

**Sheev Palpatine**

The Emperor himself [was born to a very influential family on the Mid Rim world of Naboo](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darth_Sidious) without any real connection with the Force. No strong Sith nor Jedi. Just politician, yet he became one of the strongest Sith ever lived and the one who nearly wiped out all Jedi in the galaxy. Yikes, not bad for someone without a pedigree!

**Revan**

Renowned as the Revanchist, reviled as Revan the Butcher, worshiped as the Revan, dreaded as the Dark Lord of the Sith Darth Revan, and praised as the Prodigal Knight, Revan's parents are unknown. Oh, well, we know he **had** parents, or at least Kreia tells him so, but without any connection with some famous - or infamous - Sith/Jedi. Just random unnamed dudes.

Comment: Is Revan canon?

Comment: Another Legends example is Kyp Durron, whose parents and brother have no Force sensitivity to speak of and who has more *raw power* than any other Jedi of his generation, including Luke. (Although, as he eventually learns, raw power is not usually the most important thing when using the Force.)

Comment: @Mixxiphoid It is canon that there was a Sith Lord named Revan whom the Third Legion took as a namesake. That's all; there are no canon details about their life or how similar they may or may not be to the KotOR protagonist.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid As written in the post, I refer to the Legend version of Revan. I said I was going to do one example for canon and one for legend! ;)

Comment: @RickStarrunner I know, but I thought Revan was canon material. So it made me doubt. Perhaps I should have made that more clear in the comment :). Cadence answered it pretty well actually.

Comment: Yep he's totally right! :D